# OData is broken on odata.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

All the odata urls eg: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom are returning errors.

When will this be fixed?

Comment: I think Waffles would be the guy to ask about this. He's pretty knowledgeable.

Answer (score 5):

The huge amount of outages Data Explorer has been seeing is possibly due to our OData implementation.

To ensure this is the case we have disabled it temporarily, it should be up again in a week or two.

Comment: Interesting debugging technique ... ;) That aside it would be nice to hook an appropriate information right there to save users from having to search for information over here first, plus you'd likely save yourself from those [nasty duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57669) ;) Proactively posting the information here at least is still appreciated of course, thanks!

Comment: I just realized OData is up again - did your debugging technique work out, i.e. do you know now whether the OData implementation has actually been causing the outages?

Comment: @Steffen I committed a bunch of hacks to work around theoretical issues and its been up for longer than a week. so I guess this is status-possibly-fixed